# Trying to build .Net Framework app using AWS CodeBuild

Tags: .net, docker, aws-codebuild

I am trying to follow along with the blog post about creating custom docker images for AWS Code Build.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments-for-the-net-framework/

When I run my build, i get an error in the MSBuild execution

```
[Container] 2020/03/12 14:37:59 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: msbuild. Reason: exit status 3221225785
```

Has anyone else been able to successfully followed that post and gotten the build to work?  There are not any more details about the error, so I am struggling to figure out why it is failing.

Thanks,
Kim

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-runtime
```

... in the blog post where it mentions file `C:\BuildTools\Dockerfile`, please change to:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore
```

Seemed some breaking changes happened in that image:

- https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/521
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4542617/you-might-encounter-issues-when-using-windows-server-containers-with-t

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense and I did update my docker container, but unfortunately I am still getting the same error message.